# maven, package without recompile a module

Tags: maven

I have a war module (C) that depends on two other modules (A,B). When I change A and do repackaging for C `mvn package` then B got recompiled as well (although nothing in it changes), and takes a lot of time. How do I tell maven to skip that?
Tks.

Comment: how do you know that B is recompiled? Also, is B a child module of C?

Comment: do you have dependency between A and B?

Comment: @yair because I see it in the log, it's do a compiling, then a test, yes B is a child of C.

Comment: @AlexanderKudrevatykh yes, A does depend on B.

Answer (score 1):

Use the new compiler plugin version 3.1. It conducts an incremental compile which works marvellously for me. It does a complete compile when it finds changes in a module, else it does not compile anything.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html

Incremental mode is the default, so in fact there is nothing else to do than updating the version!

Of course you should not perform a clean in advance. This would lead to a full compile always.

Comment: thanks, it worked, well, partly. Maybe another follow-up question: I can see it said: changes detected, recompile... But on some modules nothing really change (I'm absolutely sure since I didn't even open the code files of those module), any idea what "changes" in maven context mean?

Comment: @Tungmaile: The plugin does not apply any smart algorithm. If you changed something in module B and A depends on it, it will build both. Doesn't matter if those changes have any effect on A. This also is a strength: you can run it on Jenkins and there won't be any issues regarding "smart" incremental compilation.

Comment: WARNING! When I evaluated maven-compiler-plugin's incremental compilation in November 2013, it in fact did not rebuild module A, when B changed. Which basically means that incremental compilation is broken, and it's dangerous to enable it. Also it was disabled by default, since `useIncrementalCompilation=true` in fact disables it due to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-209

Answer (score 0):

Remove `B` from the project by excluding it from the relevant parent POM. You could do so in a development profile. This way, it is loaded from the maven cache rather than recompiled every time.

Comment: yes that's what I'm doing, but I'm looking for a better way, since if I forgot to change the parent POM file back and commit it, my teammates will yell at me :-p

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the option -pl. Pl stands for "project list". You type

mvn -pl myProjA,myProjB clean install

This would build only those two projects. But beware, you might oversee necessary projects to build.

http://java.dzone.com/articles/5-maven-tips

I was not able to find this on the maven docs, but I'm sure it's there, too.